Horizontal ellipsoid artifacts when printing an image with barcodes
I tried to print some PDF files, but even after several attempts, replacing ink cartridges, changing drivers, and switching from wireless to wired, I still get some ellipsoid artifacts that prevent barcodes from being machine-readable.
I'm using Linux (Fedora 40), and tried using wireless printing on a Canon Pixma TS5000. I have been using this printer for years via a USB cable, and recently started using wireless printing, and didn't have any issues in the past. I recently upgraded from Fedora 38, which may or not explain it.
(I'm really sorry for the poor image quality; also, I redacted some codes in red, which might be unnecessary, but just in case...)
Here's my first printing attempt:

The bar codes are unreadable, and several parts of the text as well. I tried replacing one of the black ink cartridges (this printer has two of them, the other still had lots of ink) and tried again:

It is slightly better, but still too many defects that prevent the barcode from being read. Also, notice they are not deterministic. I tried changing the driver, printing using a different PDF reader, printing from a rasterized file, but still got defects in all of them, for instance:

I finally tried using the USB cable again, and got a slightly better result, but the barcode area is still missing some lines:

On a different page, I had the same issue, but the barcode was laid down horizontally and very wide, so there is at least one continuous line allowing a barcode scanner to read it:

Again, these artifacts are non-deterministic, even if I re-print using exactly the same settings/driver/etc. They do tend to produce "similarly flawed" images, but the exact size and position of the ellipses varies a bit between attempts.
Finally, I tried printing a test page, and we can still see some minor ellipses inside the colored circle, which might disprove a direct connection with the black ink cartridges:

It's not clear at all to me if these are caused by hardware (ink cartridges? old printer?), software (faulty drivers? wireless issues?), or a combination of both.
I'm mostly interested in learning what might cause this kind of artifacts. I have never seen this kind of failure mode in a printer and I cannot find references to it on the internet.
An important note: the first 4 pictures were printed in landscape. All of the ellipses were produced "horizontally" by the printer.


"Finally, I tried printing a test page, and we can still see some minor [voids or lacunae ed.] inside the colored circle." The image shows a page sent from Linux [likely using cups].
Try printing a test page using the printer controls. Check the nozzle spray pattern and adjust it.
See the Web Manual for correcting other issues.
Clean the paper path to remove lint.

Have you tried printing as an image and also adjusting print quality?

In the printer Properties dialog, you should find settings to increase resolution (points par centimètre or dots per inch), and turn on or off antialiasing.
In the Print dialog, there is a setting to Print as Images. The downside of doing so is that more data needs to be sent, so it might take a bit longer to print... or not.

Try printing directly fromcups. In terminal, for example, use
lp -o media=A4 -o resolution=600dpi <filename>
to set resolution and paper size.


4.. Try using yet another PDF reader to print documents than the Fedora default. KDE Okular is a free native Linux document reader, but I find the free Windows applications Sumatra PDF Reader and PDF-XChange Editor run quite well under wine, and are far faster to start than Okular.
Note
Modern printer firmware checks for the printing of paper currency and will intentionally create artifacts to make printout non-negotiable, but I've not seen that for barcodes.

paper currency printing: At least some printers (historic fact?) also include printer identity / tracing / counter measure information - e.g. if you see excessive yellow ink consumption.
